# How can I set up gymnastic rings?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, home-exercise, bodyweight, gymnastics, rings

I am a gymnastics beginner who doesn't want to join a club, nor do I have rings, or a bar for pull-ups, front lever (progressions). However I do have paralletes.

I was wondering they cheapest, easiest way to set up rings and a bar in my backyard (I think the rings would hang from the bar, which would be around 2.5 metres high). I have concrete/a flat surface to put a base on I was also wondering what kind of rings — wooden, plastic, Xtreme, etc.? Cost is a serious factor for me, I'm looking to build strength and coordination, not hyperthy or for a gymnastics competition. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Man I am going to tell you not to do this. Gymnastic exercises are done on secure equipment which is well maintained and practice is performed with spotters - for good and obvious reasons.

If you're really not going to be doing any double dislocates but essentially just hanging from it and lifting your body weight, then you want to consult someone who understands the strength of materials under stress- an engineer. Not someone here who may only know HOW to use equipment, but not make it.

Maybe you can buy equipment specifically made for this purpose, but you still have to worry about maintenance and attaching it properly. I am not saying it's rocket-science, I am saying it's high stakes for you if things go wrong and you owe it to yourself to get definitive answers to this question from truly qualified sources.

Best of luck.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Maybe this should be a comment